# how to plot the amplitude and phase spectrum of a Fourier Transform in this specific pattern?

Tags: plotting, fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I'd like to plot the Amplitude, and phase angle spectrum of the `FourierTransform[Exp[-a t] UnitStep[t], t, ω, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]`  (The Fourier transform is gonna be: `1/(a + I ω)`)

I'm new to Mathematica;  I'd like to plot this by keeping `a` as a variable in the plot. In other words: Horizontal axis (`ω`) is from `-2 a` to `2 a` (exactly in this sorting: `-2 a`, `-a`, `0`, `+a`, `+2 a`.) (obviously, the plot has to be continuous but i'd like these horizontal axis points to appear as bold dots on the continuous plot. also please mention another version in which the horizontal axis points form a discrete plot(not continuous anymore). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. You might want to consider using the code markup feature provided by the site for commands like FourierTransform. Not so critical for this post but if you provide more code it makes things much more legible.

Answer (score 7):

I'll show the easy way, then the hard way.

### Easy way

Since the Fourier transform is the Laplace transform when real of `s` is zero, then you can use `BodePlot`

```
ft = FourierTransform[Exp[-a t] UnitStep[t], t, w, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ft = ft /. (I*w) -> s
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
BodePlot[TransferFunctionModel[(ft /. a -> 1), s]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can improve the plot like this

```
ft = FourierTransform[Exp[-a t] UnitStep[t], t, w, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]
ft = ft /. (I*w) -> s    
tf = TransferFunctionModel[(ft /. a -> 1), s];
BodePlot[tf, GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 400,
 FrameLabel -> {{{"magnitude (db)", None}, {None, "Bode plot"}},
   {{"phase(deg)", None}, {"Frequency (rad/sec)", None}}},
 ScalingFunctions -> {{"Log10", "dB"}, {"Log10", "Degree"}}, 
 BaseStyle -> 14]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Hard way

```
ft = FourierTransform[Exp[-a t] UnitStep[t], t, w, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}];
LogLinearPlot[20*Log10[Abs[(ft /. a -> 1)]], {w, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 LogLinearPlot[Arg[(ft /. a -> 1)]*180/Pi, {w, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Extra credit**

Here is a Manipulate

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{ft, t, s, w, tf, a0},
  ft = FourierTransform[Exp[-a0 t] UnitStep[t], t, w, 
    FourierParameters -> {1, -1}];
  ft = ft /. (I*w) -> s;
  tf = TransferFunctionModel[(ft /. a0 -> a), s];
  BodePlot[tf, GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 400,
   FrameLabel -> {{{"magnitude (db)", None}, {None, "Bode plot"}},
     {{"phase(deg)", None}, {"Frequency (rad/sec)", None}}},
   ScalingFunctions -> {{"Log10", "dB"}, {"Log10", "Degree"}}, 
   BaseStyle -> 14]
  ],
 {{a, 1, "a"}, .1, 10, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 ContinuousAction -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> {a}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You could just do `ft = FourierTransform[...]; BodePlot[ft /. a -> 1, w]`.

Comment: @SubaThomas at school we only learned to use Bode on Laplace transforms. That is why I changed it. But why does they give different output? i.e. compare `ft = FourierTransform[Exp[-a t] UnitStep[t], t, w, 
   FourierParameters -> {1, -1}];
BodePlot[TransferFunctionModel[(ft /. a -> 1), w]]`  to the following `ft = ft /. (I*w) -> s;
BodePlot[TransferFunctionModel[(ft /. a -> 1), s]]`. They do not look the same. Specially the phase plot?

Comment: More likely you forgot all of the details you learnt :). Given the transfer function $1/(s+a)$ in terms of the Laplace variable $s$, to get the [`BodePlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BodePlot.html) we first have to obtain the sinusoidal transfer function $1/(s+ i\  w)$ in terms of the frequency (Fourier) variable $w$. In some situations, as is the case here when we have the sinusoidal transfer function, computing the transfer function is a round trip operation.

Comment: The usage of [`TransferFunctionModel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransferFunctionModel.html) is `TFM[tf in terms of Laplace variable, Laplace variable]` not `TFM[sinusoidal transfer function, frequency variable]`. (For discrete-time it is the Z-transform and frequency variables.) To see the sinusoidal transfer function in each case do `TransferFunctionModel[(ft /. a -> 1), w][I w]` and you will see they are $1/(1-w)$ and $1/(1+i\ w)$ and hence the discrepancy.